# Quitar el foco de un EditText al presionar fuera de el en Android

Tags: java, android, android-layout

Tengo varios `EditText` y otros componentes, intento que al presionar fuera del `EditText` pierde el foco y se oculte el teclado.

**layout.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/textview_1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:imeOptions="flagNoExtractUi"
            android:inputType="textUri"
            android:singleLine="true"
            tools:text="Dummy text" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/textview_2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:imeOptions="flagNoExtractUi"
            android:inputType="textUri"
            android:singleLine="true"
            tools:text="Dummy text 2" />

        <Switch
            android:id="@+id/switch_1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Siempre se queda el foco en el último `EditText`, por ejemplo si se pulsa sobre el `switch` opera correctamente, pero manteniendo el foco a EditText, con lo cual que el teclado si está visible molesta en pantalla.

Comment: La idea de la pregunta es correcta, pero fue reportada como demasiado amplia, porque no incluye un ejemplo ni codigo ni nada. Podrias completarla un poco mas? Es un mal ejemplo para los nuevos usuarios.

Comment: Puede ser... pero como la reportaron.. es para que quede mas linda.. ahi parece mas completa.. aunque sea un ejemplo que se pueda pegar en algun lado como para reproducir el problema...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Buscando por [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36889141/hide-keyboard-in-fragment-on-outside-click) he encontrado la solución:

La técnica es interceptar el toque en pantalla comprobar que el foco lo tenia un `TextView` y removerlo

```
@Override
public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    Log.i(TAG, "dispatchTouchEvent: ");
    if (ev.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        View view = getCurrentFocus();
        if (view != null && view instanceof EditText) {
            Rect r = new Rect();
            view.getGlobalVisibleRect(r);
            int rawX = (int)ev.getRawX();
            int rawY = (int)ev.getRawY();
            if (!r.contains(rawX, rawY)) {
                view.clearFocus();
                InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(v.getWindowToken(), 0);
            }
        }
    }
    return super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);
}
```

Para que tenga enfecto se debe añadir al layout padre `android:focusableInTouchMode="true"` en mi caso uso `DrawerLayout` lo he tenido que poner en `CoordinatorLayout` de `app_bar.xml`